# Angular 6 - Custom CSS not being loaded when in production

Tags: css, angular, deployment

I've included a Bootstrap theme into my app. I've copied the file into src folder (the same level as styles.css) and added it as the last css in angular.json like this:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/WFRH-Web",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css",
              "src/theme_minco.min.css"
```

and the styles are working correctly when in dev mode but they don't work after deploying my app.

The steps I use for deploying are:

```
1) ng build --prod
2) firebase deploy
```

I've also tried using an include in styles.css and only leaving styles.css in angular.json like this:

```
@import "theme_minco.min.css";
```

to no avail because it's not working either (it only works in dev).

Any help, please?

Comment: May you prepare a [mcve] ? What happens if you run `ng serve --prod` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response @Massimo Costa. Good point, I've tried ng serve --prod and it does not work either, so the problem should be around compiling to prod but I'm not sure how to prepare you an example.

Comment: a minimal app using the CSS and use the same configuration

Comment: I guess that as it's a Bootstrap theme (they use the same classes) it could have to do with Boootstrap classes getting mixed with theme classes or theme classes being loaded before Bootstrap classes. I'm investigating this and I'll think in a way of preparing a demo.

Comment: We had a similar prob, try disabling the extractCss flag in angular.json for your prod configuration

Comment: Although I'm using a Bootstrap theme I was leaving the inclusion of Bootstrap css in angular.json just in case, but noticed that if I remove it and leave only the custom Bootstrap css then it works as expected. I don't know why in dev it works but anyway the problem dissapears this way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disable the extractCss flag in angular.json for your prod configuration